# How to initialize a group of variables respect to specific string?

Tags: python

I am trying to define a series of variables in  a quick way. eg:

variable_names=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]

Python won't allow me to do that unless I define each element first. Is there a quick way to define all of them with none value so that I can assign values to those elements later? Because I want to use a for loop to assign values to elements in variable_names.

Moreover, it there a way I can create variables names according to a specific string?

For example:
temp='01'

I want to have variable_names changes to [a01,b01,c01,d01,e01,f01,g01], the elements are all variables that can be assigned values not strings.

I will be really appreciated if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may be better off with using a dictionary.  A dictionary would allow you to define values on the fly and easily loop over the keys/values later as needed.

If that works for you, you can use `defaultdict` to create a dictionary with values defaulting to `None`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# all keys will default to 
myvalues = defaultdict(lambda: None)

# you can check that values are None
assert myvalues['newkey'] == None
```

Comment: thanks for the help. But I do not quite understand. I try to set up like:
from collections import defaultdict
variables=defaultdict(lambda: None)
assert variables['newkey'] == None
but newkey is not a variable that I can assign value

Comment: Yes, it's a dictionary to which you can assign values to specific `keys`.  It's a change in the way you're proposing to handle data.  Ask yourself do you really _need_ to have variables? Are dictionary key/value pairs enough?